# Add jquery to django

Tags: jquery, django

I can't add jquery to django app.

What I did wrong? Button click didn't have any results.

My code

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
            ...
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**main_list.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
            <div>
                <h1> Button </h1>
                <a class="likebutton" id="like" data-catid="AAA" href="#">Like</a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#like").click(function(){
                    alert('Test Ajax');
                });
            </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#like` button handler is defined *before* jQuery is loaded. You should place the script tag in the head or write the script after.

Comment: Thank you. It solves my problem. But I read that js files should be at the end of page. What is the best solution for me?

Comment: The location of the script tags doesn't matter. However, you should make them async of defer to improve performance, so the main thread is not blocked. Learn more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).